# Bucle for en Sass

Tags: sass

Estoy aprendiendo SASS (con formato scss) y tengo una duda con el bucle for.
Tengo **10 div** y quiero darles un **order** a cada uno de ellos. Entonces pensé en esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El tema es que el nth-child() no me admite la variable $i. 
¿Alguna forma de hacerlo? ¿Con otro selector?

Gracias.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vale ya di con la solución. Para que **nth-child()** admita esa variable, la tengo que poner como **#{$i}**. Dejo un captura de pantalla por si a alguien le pasa algo similar.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]